# Get post related on category

Tags: categories

it's a catalog website for different product. I need a function that will get the category of the selected product, and get all the product from that category

Let see an example. A table, is in wood category and kitchen. So when display table, under the table i like all the other kitchen product listed as well as all the other wood product... it good for cross selling !...

how do i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`WP_Query`'s `tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to do this. You would want the args (just on the `tax_query`, I'll leave the rest up to you, you have the documentation) to look something like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR'
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'wood'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'kitchen'
    )
),
```

That method will allow you to query as many types of posts as you like. Alternatively, you can have multiple `WP_Query`s and use [`wp_get_post_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories) to get the terms for a `foreach` to feed dynamically generated suggestions, each with its own `WP_Query`. It sorta depends how you want the output to look.

Comment: I will prefer to do a request, get all product that are wood and kitchen into an array, then add all the kitchen to this array, then all the wood to this array, the single out all the array, and get it to screen !

Comment: That would require multiple `WP_Query`s...is this question solved?